# Ubuntu 12.04: Unity stuck in 2D. Compiz crashes

Tags: unity, nvidia

I have been trying to get Unity to work in 3D and hardware wise there should be no problem.  I have the 310.14 NVIDIA driver and am using a GTX660-Ti card.  Output of:

```
unity --replace
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Fatal: No composite extension
compiz (composite) - Error: initScreen failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'composite'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'composite' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'opengl' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'opengl'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'composite' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Fatal: No composite extension
compiz (core) - Fatal: No composite extension
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What am I missing to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the nvidia-xconfig utility after install nvidia driver?
If not, open Terminal and run:

```
$ sudo nvidia-xconfig --composite

$ sudo nvidia-xconfig --add-argb-glx-visuals

$ sudo nvidia-xconfig --render-accel
```

After that, restart your computer.
Luck!